# How to get the data from nested Hashmap?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, resttemplate

This line of code returns `List<HashMap<String, String>>`

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> map=  restTemplate.postForObject(url,mvm,List.class);
```

And through this code, I can succesfully get the value of id and name in `index[0]`.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> map;
map.get(0).get("id");
map.get(0).get("name");
```

The Structure of the map

```
  HashMap<"id","1">
           <"name","john">
           <"parameters",HashMap<"key", "val"> <"key2","val2">>
```

How can I get data from parameters? thanks.

Comment: How could a `HashMap<String, String>` store a `HashMap` as value?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A `HashMap<String, String>` can't contain anything other than a String as its value. So you probably don't have a `Map<String, String>`, but a `Map<String, Object>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of parameter you could do

```
String val = ((HashMap)map.get(0).get("parameters")).get("key");
```

although you will need to change

`HashMap<String, String>` to `HashMap<String, Object>` for this to work

Comment: Thanks AbstractChaos, it worked. I can't vote up your answer due to my reputation. hope you don't mind. thanks again.

Comment: @Carnal I don't believe I can :) ErickSumugat might be able to though. Glad it helped.

Comment: @Erick Sumugat: you should accept an answer when it worked for you. This motivates other to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
((HashMap)map.get(0).get("parameters")).get(map_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
for(int i=0;i<map.size();i++){

          map.get(i).get("id");
          map.get(i).get("name");
    }
```

Save each value to your needed variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get string values from the Map since it's declared `List<HashMap<String,String>>`. If it would say `List<HashMap<String, Object>` you could do something like this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.maps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class InnerMaps {

    public InnerMaps(List<HashMap<String,Object>> outerList) {
        System.out.println("InnerMaps.<init>");
        for (HashMap<String, Object> outerMap: outerList) {
            for (String key: outerMap.keySet()) {
                Object value = outerMap.get(key);
                if (value.getClass().getName().equals(HashMap.class.getName())) {
                    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = (HashMap<String,String>)value;
                    System.out.println(key + ", hashMap:"  + hashMap );
                } else  {
                    System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<HashMap<String,Object>> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String,String> innerHashmap = new HashMap<>();
        innerHashmap.put("innerOne", "innerOneValue");
        innerHashmap.put("innerTwo", "innerTwoValue");
        HashMap<String, Object> outer = new HashMap<>();
        outer.put("one", new String("One Value"));
        outer.put("two", innerHashmap);
        theList.add(outer);
        InnerMaps app = new InnerMaps(theList);

    }
}
```